# Date range filter and One-to-Many relation query syntax

Tags: prisma

I am trying to filter booked rooms to find all available rooms:

```
model Room {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())

  roomNumber  String  @unique
  hotel       String

  bookings Booking[]
}

model Booking {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())

  hotel String

  startDate DateTime
  endDate   DateTime

  roomId Int
  room   Room @relation(fields: [roomId], references: [id])

  @@map("bookings")
}
```

I don't get the syntax of a prisma findMany query that would check, given two booking dates, all available rooms.

The mathematical logic to find if a room is **not** available is (i.e. if one booking interval crosses or contains the dates given) :

```js
(startDate <= dto.startDate && dto.startDate < endDate) ||
(startDate < dto.endDate && dto.endDate <= endDate) ||
(dto.startDate <= startDate && dto.endDate >= endDate)
```

I would appreciate any help as I don't understand quite well the order of logic filters in prisma...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `none`:

```js
prisma.room.findMany({
  where: {
    bookings: {
      none: {
        // ...
      },
    },
  },
});
```

and specify the condition for a booking that would case a conflict (i.e. make the room not available) or use `every`:

```js
prisma.room.findMany({
  where: {
    bookings: {
      every: {
        //...
      },
    },
  },
});
```

and specify the condition that bookings have to meet to not cause a conflict.

The condition you've specified seems unnecessary complex to me. Every booking that meets this condition should be a conflict:

```js
(dto.startDate <= endDate && dto.endDate >= startDate)
```

(might need some adjustment depending on how you want to treat edge cases)

All together:

```js
prisma.room.findMany({
  where: {
    bookings: {
      none: {
        endDate: { lte: dto.startDate },
        startDate: { gte: dto.endDate },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Just in case you want to specify more complex conditions using `OR` you can do like this:

```js
prisma.room.findMany({
  where: {
    bookings: {
      none: {
        OR: [
          {
            // (startDate <= dto.startDate && dto.startDate < endDate)
            startDate: { lte: dto.startDate },
            endDate: { gt: dto.startDate },
          },
          {
            // (startDate < dto.endDate && dto.endDate <= endDate)
            startDate: { lt: dto.endDate },
            endDate: { gte: dto.endDate },
          },
          {
            // (dto.startDate <= startDate && dto.endDate >= endDate)
            startDate: { gte: dto.startDate },
            endDate: { lte: dto.endDate },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but my real struggle is to express this condition (and order the logic in prisma). I believe my logic is right, it checks if it contains OR crosses with the query. (you can't book a room for 5 days if it's booked for one of these 5 days for example).

Comment: Didn't see your update, thank you a lot.